# Distance between two coordinates in php using haversine

Tags: distance, haversine

I've looked around and seen mention of the haversine formula to determine distance between two coordinates (lat1, lng1) and (lat2, lng2).

I've implemented this code:

```
    function haversineGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```

And am trying to determine:

**1) what units this is returning?  (goal being in feet)**

**2) is this equation written the right way?**

For example what should be the distance between these two points?

(32.8940695525,-96.7926336453) and (33.0642604502, -96.8064332754)?

I'm getting 18968.0903312 from the formula above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) what units this is returning? (goal being in feet)

Whatever units in which you supply the Earth's radius.

> 2) is this equation written the right way?

Test it. You can compare your results with an existing Haversine formula implementation, like [this one](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: So since I'm setting Earth's radius as $earthRadius = 6371000 would the units be in meters?