# Calculate which store is closest to user through geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm developing a website and in the contacts page I need to assist the user to find the closest store and give the user directions to it on google maps!

The company has 4 stores in the city (and I have the latitudes & longitudes for all stores).

When the user presses a button I get the latitude & longitude of the user.

So far so good! Now I need to calculate which store is closest to user. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean the actual formula? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: Have you considered using the [Google Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) to calculate the route and distance to each store and compare that?

Comment: @RobG no it's going to be to many request to send if they have more then 4 store! but tnx for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of straight line distance you can make use of the Haversine formula that calculates the distance between two points each defined by a latitude and longitude

[Haversine in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140579/distance-between-two-coordinates-in-php-using-haversine)
or
[Haversine in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913349/haversine-formula-in-python-bearing-and-distance-between-two-gps-points)

Comment: Tnx a lot just needed the name of the formula!